# Manually disable scripts(/plugins) during a session?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-vimtex

Sorry if this is a noob question(I'm new to configuring vim) but I was wondering if it is possible to disable startup scripts manually during a Vim session. I am aware of the `:scriptnames` command which lists all the scripts/plugins that vim sources. I was wondering if it would be possible to, from this list, disable scripts and see how they change the behavior.

I am using the [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin for editing LaTeX files and am facing a bit of lag when I'm typing. I would like to disable some scripts that I feel are unnecessary to see if it improves performance. What would you recommend doing when you face performance issues ?

Comment: Spelling "tek" is a major crime. As Knuth originally pointed out, "TeX" is supposed to be said as in Greek language.

Comment: @Matt crime is major hyperbole; perhaps « gaffe » or similar? Let’s assume best intentions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options, though some depend on plugin-authors to follow best-practices.

- `vim --noplugin` is kind of a nuclear option. You can combine with `-Nu NONE` or other `-u` options to get varying levels of "just my config" (though, if you put config files in `~/.vim/plugin/` like me, this will disable those too)
- `let g:loaded_<plugin> = 1`: most plugin scripts (though not all pieces of all plugins) have an include guard that stops them from executing if a special variable is already set. Have a look at the first 5 lines of code of any file you want to disable to see if you can do this. (I do it to disable certain vim-distributed plugins in my vimrc, which is generally the best place to add this; you could also do it via `--cmd`).
- Delete (or move) the offending file so it can't be found by vim—this will likely break things quickly, but it will cause the scripts not to get executed

---

Unfortunately, it's a lot harder to do this mid-session. In almost all cases, you need to do some work on vim-startup to avoid loading a file—`plugin` files are sourced on startup. Autoloaded files and many other things (e.g., colorscheme files, compiler files, ftplugin files) are sourced on-demand; some of them, you can move at any time to temporarily disable them. Others, like autoload, you can only "move-to-disable" if you haven't yet triggered a function from that file.

If you really want to muck about with files like this, I recommend giving `:help startup` a good long read.

---

In some cases, `:debug` can be a better fit for tracking down a bug.

---

In many cases, `:help profile` can help you find out where performance issues are.

Comment: Wow ! I had completely forgotten about this. Apologies for the incredibly delayed repsonse. I've found using `:profile` to be really helpful. Thanks.